# c# CompareTo() Method

Tags: c#, string, methods

I'm trying to understand CompareTo() in C# and the following example made me more confused than ever. Can someone help me understand why the result for the 3rd variation is 1? 2nd word in the sentence "Hello wor**d**d" is not the same as str1 "Hello wor**l**d" so why am I getting 1? Shouldn't I get -1?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str1 = "Hello world";
        Console.WriteLine(str1.CompareTo("Hello World"));
        Console.WriteLine(str1.CompareTo("Hello world"));
        Console.WriteLine(str1.CompareTo("Hello wordd"));

    }
```

Results: -1, 0, 1

Comment: What leads you to think you should get -1? That would suggest that "Hello world" should come before "Hellow wordd" in a sorted list, which would seem odd to me.

Comment: Required reading: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=net-5.0#returns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the strings match, then CompareTo() gives 0. If they don't match, it gives a positive or negative number depending on which string comes first alphabetically.

In your example, both the results 1 and -1 indicate the strings do not match, while 0 indicates the strings match.

It looks like you are using it to determine equality and not to sort. If this is the case, then you should use `Equals()` instead.

Comment: Well, it gives a positive or negative number depending on which comes first. You should never assume that the result will always be -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: Are -1 and 1 equally false in this context?

Comment: @ProgLog What do you mean by "equally false"?

Comment: I mean both are not true.

Comment: Yes, results of 1 and -1 both indicate the two strings do not match.

Answer (score 2):

The `String.CompareTo` method compares this instance with a specified `object` or `String` and returns an `integer` that indicates whether this instance precedes.

- if the return value is **Less than zero**: This instance **precedes** value.
- if the return value is **Zero**: This instance has the **same position** in the sort order as value.
- if the return value is **Greater than zero**: This instance **follows** value.
  -or-
  value is null.